# How to get camera to follow car

Tags: python, pygame, racing

i am making a top down racing game where the car progresses along the track, however i need the camera follow the car as it progresses through the track. I am unsure how to fix the error. I am new to python/pygame so sorry for any obvious errors. :P thanks

P.S. the background and camera code is towards the bottom

```
import os
import pygame
import random
from tkinter import *
from math import tan, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2
from Login import *

class Buttons:
#window
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Race!", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

root = Tk()
b = Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()


###############################################################
#music player
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE)
rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#music
pygame.mixer.music.load("GasGasGas.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
###############################################################


class Car:
    def __init__(self, x, y, angle=0.0, length=4, max_steering=30, max_acceleration=5.0):
        self.position = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = angle
        self.length = length
        self.max_acceleration = max_acceleration
        self.max_steering = max_steering
        self.max_velocity = 20
        self.brake_deceleration = 10
        self.free_deceleration = 2

        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0

    def update(self, dt):
        self.velocity += (self.acceleration * dt, 0)
        self.velocity.x = max(-self.max_velocity, min(self.velocity.x, self.max_velocity))

        if self.steering:
            turning_radius = self.length / tan(radians(self.steering))
            angular_velocity = self.velocity.x / turning_radius
        else:
            angular_velocity = 0

        self.position += self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * dt
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Project BrmBrm")
        width = 1280
        height = 720
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ticks = 60
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        image_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "RedLambo.png")
        car_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        car = Car(0, 0)
        ppu = 32

        while not self.exit:
            dt = self.clock.get_time() / 1000

            # Event queue
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.exit = True

            # User input
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                if car.velocity.x < 0:
                    car.acceleration = car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration += 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                if car.velocity.x > 0:
                    car.acceleration = -car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration -= 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.brake_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.brake_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            else:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.free_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.free_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    if dt != 0:
                        car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            car.acceleration = max(-car.max_acceleration, min(car.acceleration, car.max_acceleration))

            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                car.steering -= 500 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                car.steering += 500 * dt
            else:
                car.steering = 0
            car.steering = max(-car.max_steering, min(car.steering, car.max_steering))

            # Logic
            car.update(dt)

            # Drawing
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, car.angle)
            rect = rotated.get_rect()
            self.screen.blit(rotated, car.position * ppu - (rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2))
            pygame.display.flip()

            self.clock.tick(self.ticks)
        pygame.quit()

##########track
BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface((1280, 800))
BACKGROUND.fill((127, 69, 2))
BACKGROUND = pygame.image.load("track1.png").convert()
screen.blit(BACKGROUND,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()


############background

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

background = Background(BACKGROUND, [0, 0])
camera = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)


screen.blit(background.image, background.rect.topleft+camera)


for sprite in Car:
    screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move the car you need to move the camera vector with the same velocity as well. Then you can subtract the camera from the positions of the game objects to offset them.

I've modified your code and adjusted some values to make it work (I didn't know what the purpose of the `ppu` variable was, but I had to remove it). The `camera` vector is now an attribute of the car, because that way it was easier to update it.

```
import pygame
import random

from math import tan, radians, degrees, copysign
from pygame.math import Vector2


pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800), pygame.RESIZABLE)
rect = screen.get_rect()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BACKGROUND = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
# Drawing a grid.
for x in range(screen.get_width()//20):
    pygame.draw.line(BACKGROUND, (160, 90, 0), (x*20, 0), (x*20, 800), 1)
for y in range(screen.get_height()//20):
    pygame.draw.line(BACKGROUND, (160, 90, 0), (0, y*20), (1280, y*20), 1)


class Car:
    def __init__(self, image, x, y, angle=0.0, length=4, max_steering=10, max_acceleration=5.0):
        self.orig_image = image
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.position = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = angle
        self.length = length
        self.max_acceleration = 450
        self.max_steering = max_steering
        self.max_velocity = 220
        self.brake_deceleration = 150
        self.free_deceleration = 100

        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0
        self.camera = Vector2(0, 0)  # Assigned the camera as an attribute.

    def update(self, dt):
        self.velocity += (self.acceleration * dt, 0)
        self.velocity.x = max(-self.max_velocity, min(self.velocity.x, self.max_velocity))

        if self.steering:
            turning_radius = self.length / tan(radians(self.steering))
            angular_velocity = self.velocity.x / turning_radius / 2
        else:
            angular_velocity = 0

        vel = self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * dt
        self.position += vel
        self.camera += vel  # Update the camera position as well.
        # If you use the rect as the blit position, you should update it, too.
        self.rect.center = self.position
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * dt

        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.display.set_caption("Project BrmBrm")
        width = 1280
        height = 720
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ticks = 60
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        car_image = pygame.Surface((68, 43), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.polygon(car_image, pygame.Color('dodgerblue1'), ((0, 0), (68, 20), (0, 41)))
        car = Car(car_image, *self.screen.get_rect().center)  # I center the car.

        while not self.exit:
            dt = self.clock.tick(self.ticks) / 1000
            # Event queue
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.exit = True

            # User input
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                if car.velocity.x < 0:
                    car.acceleration = car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration += 890 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                if car.velocity.x > 0:
                    car.acceleration = -car.brake_deceleration
                else:
                    car.acceleration -= 1 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.brake_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.brake_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            else:
                if abs(car.velocity.x) > dt * car.free_deceleration:
                    car.acceleration = -copysign(car.free_deceleration, car.velocity.x)
                else:
                    if dt != 0:
                        car.acceleration = -car.velocity.x / dt
            car.acceleration = max(-car.max_acceleration, min(car.acceleration, car.max_acceleration))

            if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                car.steering -= 20 * dt
            elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                car.steering += 20 * dt
            else:
                car.steering = 0
            car.steering = max(-car.max_steering, min(car.steering, car.max_steering))

            # Logic
            car.update(dt)

            # Drawing
            self.screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
            # Now use the camera to adjust the positions of the game objects.
            screen.blit(BACKGROUND, -car.camera)
            self.screen.blit(car.image, car.position - (car.rect.width / 2, car.rect.height / 2)-car.camera)
            # You can blit the car at its rect.topleft position minus the camera as well.
            # self.screen.blit(car.image, car.rect.topleft-car.camera)
            pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

I've also got [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939385/how-would-i-go-about-creating-smooth-camera-movement-in-pygame) on Stack Overflow in which I demonstrate how a smooth camera effect can be achieved in pygame.

Comment: Thank you! I notice there is now a grid which is great. When designing a race track how would i make some of the grid a 'wall'. I do have many questions however i will likely make new posts for them when the time comes